# Obtain layout from a graph object

Tags: r, igraph

This is a simple question, but I can't seem to find documentation for it. I have a graph object that was created by taking the union of two graphs. I would like to output the layout function that was created during the merge.

```
a <- barabasi.game(10)
b <- barabasi.game(20)

ab <- union(a,b)
```

Ideally, I'd like to visualize the union in a way that places subgraphs (a,b) in their own "space." Is there a default function in `igraph` for outputting the layout of a graph object?

Comment: Some remarks: #1 Please add the required packages (`library(igraph)`) #2 and set a seed before some random action to make things reproducible (e.g. `set.seed(1)`). #3 Afaik there is not "layout function" created during the merge (?). You can create a layout e.g. by using `layout.auto(ab)` or `layout.auto(a)` - this gives you the coordinates of the nodes/vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For igraph, layouts are matrices of coordinates. If you call any layout method, you get a matrix:

```
loa <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(a)
lob <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(a)
```

If you assign these matrices to the `layout` graph attribute, igraph will use them automatically at plotting, or you can pass them to the plot method directly:

```
b$layout <- loa
plot(a)
plot(b, layout = lob)
```

If you take the union of two graphs, their layout attributes, if they have, won't be merged, but renamed to `layout_1` and `layout_2`. If you want to keep the non-overlapping parts separated, and merge the layouts, I have this idea:

```
a <- barabasi.game(10)
b <- barabasi.game(20)
a$layout <- layout.norm(layout_with_fr(a), -1, 0, -1, 1) # each subgraph
b$layout <- layout.norm(layout_with_fr(b),  0, 1, -1, 1) # in their own space
V(a)$x <- a$layout[,1]
V(a)$y <- a$layout[,2]
V(b)$x <- b$layout[,1]
V(b)$y <- b$layout[,2]
V(a)$color <- 'blue'
ab <- union(a, b)
V(ab)$x <- vapply(seq(vcount(ab)),
               function(vid){
                   ifelse(is.na(V(ab)$x_1[vid]),
                       V(ab)$x_2[vid],
                       V(ab)$x_1[vid])
               }, 0.0)
V(ab)$y <- vapply(seq(vcount(ab)),
               function(vid){
                   ifelse(is.na(V(ab)$y_1[vid]),
                       V(ab)$y_2[vid],
                       V(ab)$y_1[vid])
               }, 0.0)
ab$layout <- cbind(V(ab)$x, V(ab)$y)
V(ab)$color[is.na(V(ab)$color)] <- 'yellow'
plot(ab, rescale = FALSE)
```

Here I created two layouts, one scaled to the west, other to the east half of the coordinate system. Then I merged the layouts, taking by default the coordinates from `a`, and from `b` if the vertex was not part of `b`. After making a new layout matrix from `x` and `y` coordinates, I plotted the graph with `rescale = FALSE`, so the coordinates remain unchanged.

Note: likely you want to merge your graphs not based on numberic vertex IDs, but by names. For this, create a `name` vertex attribute, and pass the `byname = TRUE` parameter to the `union` method.